# Automatic jquery resubmit works for hard-coded values in form, but not for PHP variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, variables

I have used

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to reload the page automatically when a user chooses to set a limitation through an option in a form (in this case 'material').
This works perfectly for hard coded options, but nor for those that are drawn from my mySQL database through PHP. So:

```
<form id="material" class="floatleft" method="POST" action="detail.php?material=">
<select name="material" id="material" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

works with hard coded 'linen'

```
echo '<option value="linen" ';
if ($material == "linen")
 echo 'selected="selected"';
echo '>Linen</option>';
```

but not with 'linen' when retrieved from a PHP query

```
$i = 0;
while ($row_material = mysqli_fetch_array($result_material))
 {
 echo '<option value="'.$material.'" ';
 if ($material == $row_material['material'])
   echo 'selected="selected"';
 echo '>'.$row_material['material'].'</option>';
 $i++;
 }
```

Grateful for your help

Comment: incorrect closing (>)tag in option, selected is outside of (>)

Comment: How are you trying to access the posted parameters?

Comment: $material = $_POST ['material'], if that is what you mean

Comment: Sorry, about the problem with >. I changed this to make the code more readable ... My fault. Undid it now. Anyway, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to your code. I have used the [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator which will make the code more readable

```
    $array = array(
        array('material' => 'linen'),
        array('material' => 'test'),
        array('material' => 'test2'),
        array('material' => 'test3'),
    );
    echo '<select>';

    $material = 'test2';
    foreach($array as $row_material)
    {
        $selected = ($material == $row_material['material']) ? 'selected=true' : ''; 
         echo '<option value="'. $row_material['material'] .'" ' .$selected .' >' .  $row_material['material'].'</option>';
         $i++;  
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: This does not seem to change anything, still the same problem.

Comment: can you print `$material` && `$row_material['material']` in the while loop?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean: here is the web page, if that makes it clearer: http://www.trismegistos.org/words/detail.php?lemma=%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%89&type=verb. Middle of the page, to the right of the number of results: 'Pottery' is hard-coded and works, pottery (2) is drawn from PHP and does not work.

Comment: @MarkD Check the answer, i have made a sample for this. Also there was mistake in my previous answer. I fixed it. Try to use this one.

Comment: works perfectly now, thanks a lot! Although I must admit I do not know why ... `   foreach($result_material as $row_material)
    {
        $selected = ($material == $row_material['material']) ? 'selected=true' : ''; 
         echo '<option value="'. $row_material['material'] .'" ' .$selected .' >' .  $row_material['material'].' ('.$row_material['frequency'].')</option>';
         $i++;  
    }` Upvoted you, but my reputation is not yet sufficient for this vote to be taken into account ...

Comment: Not an issue. Please accept it if its working for you. `foreach` is just for demo purposes as i didn't have the database.

Answer (score 0):

Close the `<option>` in the last echo, not the first:

```php
echo '>'.$row_material['material'].'</option>';
```

Comment: Sorry, had done that already. I changed this to make the code more readable ... My fault. Unidid it now. Anyway, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Try debugging the `$row_material` variable or take a look for some warnings (error_log).

Comment: No error warnings as far as I can see. And the $row_material variable seems to be fine, at least it prints. Here is the web page, if that makes it clearer: trismegistos.org/words/…. Middle of the page, to the right of the number of results: 'Pottery' is hard-coded and works, pottery (2) is drawn from PHP and does not work.